# Trello creating calendar processes

Tags: trello

Is there any way to create cards with a start and due date that spans for a period of time in the calendar view? My in-laws own a property which is occasionally rented out for private parties or conferences and I want to set up some simple lists for general to-dos, like shopping or cleaning or whatever, and also for reservations that might span over a weekend.

Is there any other way than copying multiple cards for each day of the reservation? And if that is the only way, is there any way for cards to relate to each other like in Jira?